# EE3 Template Viewing Revisions Problem

Tags: ee, revisions

I'm currently testing the latest EE3 version and for some reason, when trying to view any revisions, all that keeps getting displayed is the latest version.  This issue occurs across all template groups.  I was previously running EE3.0.3 and just updated EE3.0.4 and it still persists.

Upon further inspection, each view button URL links to the same current template revision number.  It's the only issue I found not quite working right in EE thus far.  The following is my current setup

EE 3.0.4
MAMP Pro 3.3
PhP 5.6.10
MySQL 5.5.42

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If the links are the same (while they should not be) then this must be a bug, and you are encouraged to report it directly to EllisLab using their [bugtracker](https://support.ellislab.com/bugs)

Answer (score 0):

There was indeed a [bug](https://support.ellislab.com/bugs/detail/21482/) concerning revisions. It should be fixed in EE 3.1.1.